# Lodash swap adjacent items if condition is met

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, lodash

Say I have an array, `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 3, 4, 6, 3, 7, 4]`. I want to swap the values of 3 and 4 iff they are adjacent an in the order `[3, 4]` (i.e. `[4, 3]` remain intact). The result of the example would be `[1, 2, 4, 3, 5, 4, 3, 6, 3, 7, 4]`.

Is there an **elegant** way to do this in Lodash without the use of `for` loops?

Edit:
How about

```
 _.sortBy(arr, function(value, index) {
    if (value === 3) {
        return index + 0.75;
    } else if (value === 4) {
        return index - 0.75;
    } else {
        return index
    }
});
```

Edit 2:
Went with the following (it's not actually 3 and 4).

```
return _.reduce(tags, function(out, tag) {
    var word = tag[0];

    if (out[0] && unitPowerSuffixes.hasOwnProperty(word)) {
        out.splice(-1, 0, {
            type: 'unit-power',
            value: unitPowerSuffixes[word]
        }); // Insert one from end
    } else {
        out.push(tag);
    }

    return out;
}, []);
```

Comment: Perhaps you may want to use array.filter (_.filter in lodash), but I don't have a clear idea of how to preserve [4,3]

Comment: I think you should [post your `sortBy` solution as an answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer), not in your question

Comment: What should happen to `[4, 3, 4, 3]`, should it become `[4, 4, 3, 3]`?

Comment: @Bergi A better question is what should happen to `[3, 4, 4, 4]`? Should it become `[4, 4, 4, 3]` or should it become `[4, 3, 4, 4]`?

Comment: The former, I guess. It's not too important actually!

Answer (score 1):

> Is there an **elegant** way to do this in Lodash without the use of `for` loops?

Yes, you can use `reduce` as follows:

```js
var array  = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 3, 4, 6, 3, 7, 4];

var result = _.reduce(array, swapAdjacentInOrder(3, 4), []);

alert(JSON.stringify(result));

function swapAdjacentInOrder(a, b) {
    return function (result, element) {
        var length = result.length;

        if (length > 0 && element === b) {
            var last = length - 1;

            if (result[last] === a) {
                result[last] = b;
                element = a;
            }
        }

        result[length] = element;

        return result;
    };
}
```

```html
<script src="https://rawgit.com/lodash/lodash/master/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

However, the `swapAdjacentInOrder` function also has the following property:

```js
var array  = [3, 4, 4, 4];

var result = _.reduce(array, swapAdjacentInOrder(3, 4), []);

alert(JSON.stringify(result)); // [4, 4, 4, 3]

function swapAdjacentInOrder(a, b) {
    return function (result, element) {
        var length = result.length;

        if (length > 0 && element === b) {
            var last = length - 1;

            if (result[last] === a) {
                result[last] = b;
                element = a;
            }
        }

        result[length] = element;

        return result;
    };
}
```

```html
<script src="https://rawgit.com/lodash/lodash/master/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

If you don't want that then you can do the following updated `swapAdjacentInOrder` function:

```js
var array  = [3, 4, 4, 4];

var result = _.reduce(array, swapAdjacentInOrder(3, 4), []);

alert(JSON.stringify(result)); // [4, 3, 4, 4]

function swapAdjacentInOrder(a, b) {
    return function (result, element) {
        var length = result.length;

        if (length > 0 && element === b) {
            var last = length - 1;

            if (result[last] !== a || last > 0 && result[last - 1] === b);
            else {
                result[last] = b;
                element = a;
            }
        }

        result[length] = element;

        return result;
    };
}
```

```html
<script src="https://rawgit.com/lodash/lodash/master/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Done something like this! Yours is a lot more efficient, but I like to be very declarative. Put my solution above.

Answer (score 1):

A really functional way would be to use something like `splitOn`. But we can do that using strings (not even needing lodash):

```
arr.join().split("3,4").join("4,3").split(",").map(Number)
```